# Start activity did not work for android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activitygroup

I use my custom implementation tabhost. Create a new activity as follows:

```
public class TabsActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {
  //
  //...
  //
  private void startGroupActivity(String activityID, Intent activityIntent) {
    final LocalActivityManager localActivityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
    Window window = localActivityManager.startActivity(activityID, activityIntent);
    // after call destroy activity window equals null on android 1.6 (emulator). Why?
    // on android 2.2 window not equal null
    if (window != null) {
     View view = window.getDecorView();
     tabsContentFrameLayout.addView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }
  }
  //
  //...
  //
}
```

But after call destroy activity:

```
 getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity(className, true);
```

I'm trying to make call to start activity,  but get window equal null from this code:

```
Window window = localActivityManager.startActivity(activityID, activityIntent);
```

On a device with firmware 2.1 (Hero) and 2.2 (Desire) works all good, but on emulator with android platform not work ;(

Now I am studying source code android platform 2.2, to understand why window equal null.

I will be glad of any help.

**Temporary solution:**

```
public static boolean isEmulator(Context context) {                                                                     
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
 final String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();                                                         
 if (deviceId == null) return true;                                                                              
 if (CommonHelper.isNotNull(deviceId) && deviceId.equals(NULL_IMEI)) {return true;} else { return false;}
}

if (!isEmulator(this)) {
     getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity(className, true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the call right for start activity?

I see that [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity) takes only one parameter of Intent..

Kindly check. Also, embed within try/catch to get the exception if any..

Comment: Please see URL: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html#startActivity(java.lang.String,%20android.content.Intent)